# hard inequalities

Tags: inequality

I have to find real $x$ that satisfy the equation: $\dfrac{x^7}{7} = 1+10^{1/7}x(x^2-10^{1/7})^2$

I saw that the way is to look for solution of the form: $x = a^{1/7}+b^{1/7}$.
my question is: how can I know from the beginning that I have to find a solution of this form.

another question is:there are $n$ real numbers: $X_1,\cdots,X_n$
find the biggest $k$ that satisfy the equation for any $n$ real numbers:
$\sqrt{X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2}\geq k\min\{|X_1-X_2|,|X_2-X_3|,....,|X_{n-1} - X_n|,|X_n-X_1|\}$
my question is how to approach this question

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I think the edit by @Peter Woolfitt is not OK. IMO you are searching roots of the polynomial:
$$1+10^{\frac{1}{7}} x^5-2\times10^{\frac{1}{7}} x^3+10^{\frac{3}{7}}x-\frac{1}{7}x^7$$
(or another polynomial of degree 7).
Because the degree is odd there is at least one real root 
$$x_0 = a^{\frac{1}{7}}+ b^{\frac{1}{7}}$$
You can take $a=x_0^7, b=0$. $$ $$And please post the other question separately.

Comment: @gammatester Terribly sorry, thanks for catching that. I have fixed it in the pending edit.